# Javascript join array with brackets

Tags: javascript

In javascript I need to join an array into a string with brackets. For example `['abc', 'yte', 'juu'] => (abc)(yte)(juu)`. I need the fastest and cleanest way to do this. I tried using the array join operator but it doesnt work on the first and last element.

Comment: map and add () then join by ("")?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with template literals. Use `join()` with `)(` separator, and wrap the result with `()`:

```js
const data = ['abc', 'yte', 'juu'];

const result = `(${data.join(')(')})`;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thinking "I need the fastest and cleanest way to do this." is often not ideal.  In most cases what people want is the most readable and understandable way to implement a solution.

I quite like the following. Where we first bracket each item in the array with `map` and then `join` the items with no delimiter:

```js
const data = ['abc', 'yte', 'juu'];
let brackets = data.map(x => "(" + x + ")");
let result = brackets.join("")
console.log(result);
```

That of course takes two passes over the array. If you really must have the fastest solution just use a for loop:

```js
const data = ['abc', 'yte', 'juu'];
let result = "";
for (let item of data) {
    result += "(" + item + ")";
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce an array to a single value (be that an object, array, string, number, ...) Javascript has the [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, which achieves the desired result in a single loop and line:

```js
console.log(['abc', 'yte', 'juu'].reduce((a,v)=>`${a}(${v})`,''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const list = ['abc', 'yte', 'juu'];
const result = list.map(value => `(${value})`).join("");
console.log(result);
```